# nodejs error undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a simple webserver using node js. This is the script that I have written.

```
var connect = require('connect');

connect.createServer(
       connect.static("../angularjs")
       ).listen(5000);
```

I place the script in the nodejs directory and then I try to run it using the command "node server.js" and I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\server.js:4
       connect.static("../angularjs")
                     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\server.js:4:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I am new to javascript and request you to kindly guide.

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your version of connect does not contain static in its propertys,
you either have to downgrade your version of connect (2.xx) or try this code snippet

```
var connect = require('connect'),
serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic("../angularjs"));
app.listen(5000);
```

but before run

```
npm install serve-static
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `static` is not the property of `connect`.

According to the [phrase](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)

> [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) - previously static

I think you are using a newer version of connect than the one you code is amed to.

So you have two solutions:

- Use an older version of `connect`
- Use `serve-static` middleware instead of the `static` method